# Override/disable Aspect on runtime

Tags: java, spring-boot, aspectj

In my spring-boot application I have a dependency on external jar, which contains a class marked with annotation, on which @Aspect from this jar is being triggered.

I have dao method annotated with mu custom annotation:

```
@MyAnnotation
public void save(MyEntity entity)
{
   super.save(entity);
}
```

I have an aspect, which has an advice, sending message after save() method is called:

```
@Aspect
public class MySuperAspect
{
  @Autowired
  MessageSender messageSender;

  @Around("@annotation(MyAnnotation) && args(entity)")
  public void sendMessage(MyEntity entity)
  {
     messageSender.send();
  }
}
```

I do need Dao method from the jar, but I want to disable aspect for it.

Aspect is being created via Spring XML configuration, which is inside the jar I use as well.

I could modify the aspect itself, but it's undesirable as it's being used not only by my spring-boot app.

I tried:

- Disabling xml configuration from scanning in my spring-boot app;
- Changing xml config to annotations and filter it in scanning;
- Adding @ConditionalOnExpression and @ConditionalOnProperty on aspect to be disabled by property;

As of now the only way which works is adding @Value annotation with property by which I may control logic inside the advice, but I'm curious is this the only way to do that or probably I'm missing something?

Comment: You need to provide some more information. What does this aspect do. What is the pointcut defined to fire it. Also please make sure to share some code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop spring boot from scanning this class... Because it must be configured to scan this aspect otherwise it wouldn't be picking up and applying the aspect.